# ocr library other than tesseract-android-tools

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I have creating a ocr based android application.Is there any library available other than tesseract?Because it had deprecated from code.google.com.Asprise doesn't seem to be a platform independent OCR.I have try Ron Cemer's Java OCR library but they are trained for each of the character and fond format.

I have no options to move from this parts.Pls help for finding a suitable libarary that have simmilar performance with tesseract.

Any feedback that you provided will be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: sir,but that question related to the preprocessing and accuracy of ocr engine.But my doubt is ocr from google is drepecated now.what are the free ocr engines that is compatible with mobile ocr.?

Answer (score 3):

you might want to look at https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two.

tess-two is fork of Tesseract Tools for Android (tesseract-android-tools) that adds some additional functions. Tesseract Tools for Android is a set of Android APIs and build files for the Tesseract OCR and Leptonica image processing libraries.

This project works with Tesseract v3.02.02. The required source code for Tesseract 3.02.02 and Leptonica 1.69 is included within the tess-two/jni folder.

The tess-two subdirectory contains tools for compiling the Tesseract and Leptonica libraries for use on the Android platform. It contains an Eclipse Android library project that provides a Java API for accessing natively-compiled Tesseract and Leptonica APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Google recently released an OCR API:
https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Just add the following line to your dependecies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Introduced Machine Learning Kit (MLKit) https://developers.google.com/ml-kit although you have to work it with yourself. Atleast API is now available. There's a lot of feature aside from OCR.

```
// Face features
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.0.0'

// Text features
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.0.0'
```